# CSS float versus Javascript float

Tags: javascript, css

I know it might be early, but I'm pretty confused right now..
I'm setting an rgba a color in CSS

```
#body{ color: rgba( 100,100,100,0.3 ) }
```

When I ask Javascript to give me the computed style of this element, I get this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body)['color']
//rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.298039)
```

Where I'm expecting `rgba(100,100,100,0.3)`.

My question: Why?

How is this possible and how do I work around this?

Comment: can you tell the difference between 0.3 and 0.298039?

Comment: @Barmar That isn't the point. OP wants to know how this happens and why.

Comment: @Aquillo - They also ask how to work around it. We need to know what actual problem (if any) it is causing them.

Comment: Yep, all I meant to say is ignoring the problem is not working around it.

Comment: @Aquillo - If it is not actually causing any problem at all then ignoring it is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the fields of an `rgba()` specification appear to be converted internally to 8-bit bytes. `0.3` becomes `round(0.3 * 255) = 76`. When this is converted back to rgba format, it calculates `76/255 = 0.298039`. Because it's not stored as decimal or floating point, it loses precision during this process -- there's no way for it to know what the original setting was.

There's no difference in the actual appearance of the display, because the internal 8-bit alpha is what's actually used when rendering.

Comment: No, but if I want to check on a RGBA color a can make the same caluclation to match the css. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the root of the occurence here! Interesting to see how this works.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point in most languages including javascript is not exact.  Many numbers such as 0.3 cannot be represented precisely given the way floating point numbers are stored.  If you want to compare two floating point numbers, the typical way it is done is to round them to a couple decimal places before comparison and any differences will disappear in the rounding.

Also, since there is no visible difference between small values of opacity (beyond perhaps two decimal places), the browser may be using even fewer bits to store the opacity, thus resulting in even less precision than a normal javascript floating point value.

If you have reason to store an exact value and have that exact value preserved, then convert the number to a string and store the string in a custom property on the object.  The property will preserve the string value exactly.  If you convert that string back to a float, you will still have to live with the limitations of floating point accuracy, but it should be much more accurate than you've seen with the opacity value.

Since there's no visible difference between an opacity of 0.3 and 0.298039, can you describe what the problem really is?

Comment: That's true, but usually the difference is like the 7th or 8th decimal place.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't know why there's this much difference.

Comment: @Aquillo Javascript floats are supposed to be 64-bit floating point.

Comment: @Aquillo - Javascript floating point numbers are already doubles.  This probably has more to do with how the browser is storing the opacity number internally, not really a javascript-specific issue.

Comment: I'll bet alphas are converted to an 8-bit byte, not stored as floating point.

Comment: Hmm ok, so there's no option here to get an exact decimal without the need of rounding it?

Comment: @Aquillo - correct.  There is no option for more precision.  And, one can see why too because the browser would just be wasting storage for precision that cannot possibly be visible.  Barmar's guess is probably right - the browser is probably using an more compact format for storing the opacity value that has even less precision.

Comment: In that case, +1 since you're explaining the issue.

Comment: Well a workaround with rounding it up is possible, but i'm just flabber gasted that the browser is not storing this as 0.3. 
0.3 whould seem less storage then 0.29803. Like to know more about the storage of floats.

Comment: The real problem is that I want to match css colors against the given housestyle.
When I project gets into maintanance, a lot of this get screwed.
So if rgba(100,100,100,0.3) is used Javascript throws an error in my color checker.

Comment: @HerrWalter - to match against preset colors, you need to convert to a float and round to 2 decimal points with `toFixed(2)`.  Then, it will come out as `0.3`.  That is the usual work-around for comparing floats in javascript and this is an extreme example because of the way the browser is storing the values (even more loss of precision).

Comment: would do to, but BarMar's awnser is more precise for my ColorCheck. And yes, yo can't tell the differance. Thanks for your input and help!